# how to insert the data from one json file to many table in laravel that have related data using updateOrCreate function?

Tags: php, json, database, laravel, eloquent

I have json like this

```
[
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": Tommy,
      "hobby": Football,

    },

    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": Timmy,
      "hobby": Basketball,

    }
]
```

I have 2 tables, person and hobby.

tables have column like this:
person table (id,name),
hobby table (id, person_id, hobby_name)

1 person has many hobbies

I would like to insert the json data to two tables using updateOrCreate function. I use the updateOrCreate method because the Json will update the data every 5 seconds. I need to create if a person doesn't exist and update the hobbies if the person is exist.

Question : how to updateOrCreate that two table? because I can only do it using 1 table right now.

Comment: Hi, would be a good idea to show us how you do it for one table, then someone can simply show you how to add the code for the other table

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: what is yor current table stucture an is it empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have `Person` & `Hobby` models with their relationship in place.

Since you get the person id from the json, please make sure `Person` model has `id` in the `$fillable` as

```
protected $fillable = ['id', 'name'];
```

Now you can update or create people and their hobbies as

```
$json = '[
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Tommy",
      "hobby": "Football"

    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Timmy",
      "hobby": "Basketball"

    }
]';

//convert json into associative array 
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    // find the person with the id or create the person with the given id
    $person = \App\Person::updateOrCreate(['id' => $item['id']], $item);

    // update person's hobby or create the hobby for that person
    $person->hobbies()->updateOrCreate(
        ['person_id'  => $item['id']],
        ['hobby_name' => $item['hobby']]
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks before, but in this code, I think we can not detect that there is the same hobby_name in one person.

Comment: `$person->hobbies()->updateOrCreate(...)` checks first that `hobby_name` is already there for that person. If it is there it will update the `hobby_name` else it will create it. Did you try this code first ?

Comment: yeah, I have tried this code. It works. But I think I am wrong to make the question because I this case I give the id. How it will be done if there is no id in Json, and id will be generated using auto increment. What do you think?

Comment: Yes. But you need to pass something unique to identify existing record. Something like an email of the person.